# What delegated permission is required to access User Groups info using Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-graph-api

I have an asp.net web application configured in the Azure AD. We assigned all the delegated permissions to access Azure AD to get the signed-in user AD groups info. via Graph IE. But I am still receiving the permissions issue.

I am suspecting the "Access the directory as the signed-in user - Directory.AccessAsUser.All". Since the signed-in user may or may not have privileges to query the AD. But any thoughts on this are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation [`here`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-permission-scopes#PermissionScopeDetails), you would need following delegated permissions:

- **`Group.Read.All`** to  read group information.
- **`Group.ReadWrite.All`** to perform read/write operation on groups.

If the logged in user doesn't have these permissions, they will get access denied error.

Comment: Our requirement is to pull the roles info for the logged-in user. And we are not sure what permissions are present for the user. By registering the application in AD, doesn't the application impersonate the user and query to AD.

Comment: All the delegated permissions are set for the application, including Access the directory as the signed-in user.

Comment: But does the user has permission to manage groups? If they don't they will get error as it is a delegated permission. Essentially the application is impersonating that user. So the user needs to have permission to manage the groups.

Comment: I am not sure about the end user permissions. Is there anyway to remove the impersonation and make application to query the AD. Like SharePoint online, add-in can be installed by the administrator and provision the required permissions. Add-in will then execute the requests irrespective of the user.